# How to download YouTube videos using YouTube Api3 in Android

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

Request to guide if anyone knows that how get Youtube video type (mp4,flv etc) from youtube video url through Youtube api v3 to download video in android application.

Comment: Have you went through the API first ?

Comment: I have already use Youtube api v3 for YouTube video listing and playing by following different examples. Having Knowledge about API how to extract data from it. Through API i still not found the video type (mp4, flv etc). If you get know something about it than request to guide i shall be thankful for your guidance.